# PHP with OCI8 on windows 10 IIS Environmental Path is incorrect on phpinfo()

Tags: php, windows, path, environment-variables, oci8

Good Day.

I've successfully installed PHP 7.4.4 on a windows 10 computer with IIS.  However, when I run phpinfo(), the Environmental Path is incorrect, thus leading to the OCI8 Module not loading.

The problem is that if I run php -m, php -i, or php-cgi.exe -i through the command line the module does load, and the Environmental path is correct.

I'm guessing that there is some IIS setting or config file that is not pointing to the current environmental path as set in the control panel.

Yes FastCGI is enabled.  Any help with this would be very much appreciated, as I have searched high and low and cannot find a reason for the command line executable to work, but not  on the web.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Add `windows` to questions tags.

Comment: Have you restarted the application server or the computer after setting the path?